# What is the current solution for downloading and accessing additional assets for a react native app?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

We have a React Native app that has a lot of hi-res images and videos. We are inching closer to the 100MB limit for the Play Store. What is the current solution for downloading additional assets to the device and how does ReactNative then access them? I've found some modules that can download to the device's downloads folder, but am not sure what the approach should be for actually reading those files at run-time.

For example, we want to download some additional *.mp4 files from the web, so the app has them available for display instantly.

Comment: Android has a mechanism [APK Expansion File](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) for this use case

Answer (score 0):

To store files in the internal storage of the device you need to use something like [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs), trying to make your own version of something like that, failsafe and tested could take some time, so it's better if you just can use that.